# How can I migrate my OS Ubuntu 18.01 to an other computer, keeping all my configurations and installed programs?

Tags: drivers, compatibility, migration

I have to change my computer but I want to preserve my OS as it is now. Which is the best solution to migrate my entire OS to the new computer?
I can use TimeShift, but which compatibility problems or driver problems could I encounter?

Comment: The core question you're asking depends on the characteristics/specifications of the machines involves. Nothing like cloning or transplanting the drive and just trying it in the new one. You may find a major problem if you have an old PC (BIOS) and try the same in a new UEFI system (that really works as it should in UEFI mode only).

Comment: Good way to test that your normal backup procedure allows you to restore system completely. Especially since you have old system to go back and get anything your backup is not including. I prefer new install & restore /home. apps, perhaps /etc and any server type apps that may be in / (root). Do a new clean install and restore from backup. New install will likely be more compatible with new hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do this but few are what I would consider to be "clean". I would recommend you use rsync to copy the data from your users folder in /home to your user folder on the new machine, then install any software you want on the new machine with apt/apt-get. There are ways to duplicate installed package lists with apt/dpkg but occasionally you'll end up with a list that includes legacy packages or packages you installed by hand and it becomes a pain to resolve. I would recommend just installing what you need on the new system separately to avoid trouble.

Depending on your configuration, you may have configuration files in /etc you would want to copy, possibly things in /opt you've set up outside of the standard system, and possibly things in /var you would want. I would recommend you take the time to determine what you need, and use rsync to copy anything you specifically need to copy over, and try to just install what you need using the package management on the new system. It will take a little bit more care, but you'll have a cleaner configuration that way.

Comment: I have done as you suggest and all works fine. Thank you!